# Adding a toString method to a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, tostring

I have created a linked list class to make a simple register, where I can add and remove students from a list. However I am not sure how to create my toString method for a linked list, what is the best way of going about this? 
Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Registry {


LinkedList<Student> studentList
        = new LinkedList<Student>();
//setting my type parameter




public Registry() {}


public void addStudent(Student aStudent) {}


public void deleteStudent(int studentID) {}


public String toString(){}




public String format() {}


}
```

Comment: What you want to display for each of Linked list object ?

Comment: Do you know how to use a StringBuilder?

Comment: You can just print the details of all the students within the list with some formatting. Same as what the toString() does in Collections.

Answer (score 3):

LinkedList already has a toString() method inherited from AbstractCollection.

```
toString

public String toString()

Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists
of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator,
enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters
", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).

Overrides:
    toString in class Object

Returns:
    a string representation of this collection
```

Isn't it what you want?

Comment: That would print a list of hashcodes of the items. I think the questioner rather wants a list of items using their toString() methods instead of valueOf().

Answer (score 1):

The intent appears to be to list all the students that are stored in your linked list and not to override the `toString()` of a linked list. As long as your `Student` class overrides its `toString()` method, you are on your way. Printing the linked list will invoke its `toString()` method and give you what you want.

**Sample class overriding toString()**

```
class MyClass 
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    /* getters and setters  */

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "MyClass [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
List<MyClass>  myList = new LinkedList<MyClass>();
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setX(1);
myClass.setY(2);
myList.add(myClass);
System.out.println(myList);
```

**Prints**

> [MyClass [x=1, y=2]]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a StringBuilder and just cycle through the list.

```
public String toString(){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (Student s: students){
    sb.append(s.toString()+",");
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Include whatever info you want in your Student class toString() method.

Edit: I noticed in one of the other responses that the toString() on linked list is using String.valueOf().  I actually prefer that in most instances since it will deal with nulls, unless of course you wanted to know when a null ends up in this list.

So instead of:

```
sb.append(s.toString()+",");
```

You could use:

```
sb.append(String.valueOf(s),"+");
```

Answer (score 0):

override toString() in your Registry class

LinkedList will invoke toString() of the member objects

[Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29)

`Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by java.lang.String.valueOf(java.lang.Object).`

Answer (score 0):

1. you did not create a linked list class - you created a `LinkedList` object.
2. what you want is a toString() method for your `Registry` class

   public String toString() {
       boolean bracketAdded = false;
       StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

   ```
   for(Student student : studentList) {
       result.append(bracketAdded ? ", " : "[");
       result.append(student);
       bracketAdded = true;
   }
   result.append("]");

   return result.toString();
   ```

   }

now all that is left for you is to implement a `toString()` method for your `Student` class.